# What is sadscript? Can I use it in vb.net? Why hasn't anyone I have asked heard of it?

Tags: vb.net

The title is my question.

Basically, I have heard people speak of it before, I understand it to have something to do with vb6, and I know it lets the user code for the application, but I am unable to determine if it is a separate library or built into vb, and I cannot find documentation for it anywhere.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It must be the language that http://sadtrombone.com/ is written in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Introduction**

Sadscript is a variant of VB6 used for scripting. It isn't natively part of VB6. I've seen it used as part of VB6, rumors of it's use with python, and heard that it can be used for VB.NET.

**Acceptance**

It's been used in MMORPG engines like Elysium Diamond, PlayerWorlds, and more. It's most prominent livliness is through the MMORPG engine known as Eclipse. It's said to be an easy scripting language and there are rumors that some colleges teach this scripting language. Because of how VB6 is, [scripting alternatives for VB6 are few and far between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000025/vb6-parser-lexer-scripter/3009487#3009487) (Also see [VB6 & Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339917/luainterface-docs) ).

**Obtain**

The "SadScript Engine" (for lack of better words) itself is quite difficult to find. There appears to be no central repository, and only remants of links to it's engine. I managed to find a **[link to the SadScript 3 Engine & tutorial for MirageSource MMORPG engine](http://www.mirage-realms.com/main/community/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23)**.

**More Resources**

- [Eclipse SadScript Script repositories, tutorials, and discussion](http://www.touchofdeathforums.com/)
- [SadScript tutorial blog](http://learn-sadscript.blogspot.com/)
- (Google for more)

Answer (score 4):

Sadscript appears to be a scripting language for a mmorg engine called [Eclipse](http://www.freemmorpgmaker.com/index.php/) (not the IDE called Eclipse).  As far as I can tell, the only connection to Visual Basic is that sadscript has a very similar syntax to VB6, so it will be easy to learn if you know VB (and vice versa).

Comment: This is cool to read.. I invented SadScript for VB6 loooong ago.

Comment: @Thraka I am the creator of Eclipse, nice to meet you :)